# Using lseek() prints out repeated characters

Tags: c, file, buffer, lseek

```
char x[3];
char buff, c;
x[0]='y';
int offset, i;
int fd;

fd = open("test1.txt", O_RDONLY);
if(fd==-1){ printf("Error on fopen."); exit(1); }

offset = lseek(fd, 1, SEEK_END);
printf("Size of file is: %d. \n", offset);

for(i=offset-1; i>=0; i--)
{
  c = read(fd, &buff, 1);
  printf("The character is: %c. \n", c);
}

close(fd);
```

Running this gives me.

```
Size of file is: 6. 
The character is: . 
The character is: . 
The character is: . 
The character is: . 
The character is: . 
The character is: .
```

The test file contains only the word "TEST". I want to be able to print the word backwards.

Comment: You forgot to rewind or seek the file pointer. You are reading from the end-of-file.

Comment: Well for one thing you are printing the return value of `read` which is not the character read.  See http://linux.die.net/man/2/read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read` reads at the current position, and moves the current position forward by the amount read.

There needs to be further seeks.  Also `lseek( ..., 1, SEEK_END);`  probably ought to be `lseek(...,0, SEEK_END);`  I would be uncomfortable with seeking to beyond the file.

```
for( i = ... ) {
    lseek(fd, size - i, SEEK_BEGIN );
    read(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fstat()` to get the file size, as `lseek()` to `SEEK_END` is not guaranteed to return the size of a file, and you can use `pread()` to read a file in reverse without having to do any seeking at all.  This is without any error checking - which should be added to any code that's going to be used:

```
struct stat sb;
int fd = open("test1.txt", O_RDONLY);
fstat( fd, &sb );
while ( sb.st_size > 0 )
{
    char buff;
    sb.st_size--;
    pread( fd, &buff, sizeof( buff ), sb.st_size );
    printf( "Char read: %c\n", buff );
}
close( fd );
```